# How to convert a MyBoy save file to a No$GBA save file?

Tags: emulation, my-boy

I am playing Pokemon Ruby with my phone using MyBoy Premium, and I want to continue to play using No$GBA using my computer. The save file's format is .sav, and I think I have to convert it to .sna.

Is this possible?